# Theme options period being replaced

Tags: theme-options

I have a theme option that I use for opacity.  On the screen, I put 0.67 as the value.  But if I publish and refresh to look at the value it's coming up as 0-67.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'mctheme_option_headernav_background_opacity', array (
    'default'   => '0.67',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_title',
    'type'  => 'theme_mod',
));

$wp_customize->add_control('mctheme_option_headernav_background_opacity', array(
    'type'      => 'text',
    'label'     => esc_html__('Header/Navigation Background Opacity', 'mctheme' ),
    'section'   => 'colors'
));
```

and the used in the code used in the theme:

```
get_theme_mod('mctheme_option_headernav_background_opacity', '0.67')
```

Is there any reason this is happening?  I tried changing the control type to number but that didnt work either

Comment: Changning the sanitize callback to sanitize_text_field seems to have fixed the issue

Comment: Write the answer for your question then

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the sanitize callback to sanitize_text_field seems to have fixed the issue